# Custom 404 page causing sub file to not load javascript

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, directory

I am not 100% sure if this is my issue, but this is what I have narrowed it down to. I created a sub folder and added a file to it. When I open up this page's console, I get the following error.

Error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <   404custom:1
```

Which is just this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

My javascript files will not load because of this. I call my custom 404 page in my `.htaccess` file, like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.website.com/404custom
```

The page's destination is fine and the new sub file loads. Is the way I am calling the 404 page wrong and not able to work with a sub-folder? I do not get the error in any of my other files in the root of the site.

Comment: When you specify an absolute URL for the ErrorDocument, it will trigger a 3xx redirect - is that intentional? Is the file itself really just `404custom` - no file extension?

Comment: @w3dk it is 404custom.php. I have code in the `htaccess` which eliminates the need of calling the php extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ErrorDocument 404 http://www.website.com/404custom
> ```

Your custom error document should be defined like:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404custom.php
```

If you specify an absolute URL for the `ErrorDocument` then it will trigger an *external redirect*, you will lose all the error information and your system then processes the error document URL, which you then need to rewrite to append the `.php` extension. All of that is unnecessary and should be avoided.

If it's all on the one server then the error document should be triggered with an internal subrequest. The user never sees `/404custom.php`, only the URL that triggered the error in the first place.

You also need to make sure that your error documents are excluded from any rewrites you might already be doing (like appending file extensions etc.)